# Image size proportionate to screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am making an universal app for the first time. I want to change my image size according to screen size for it to look bigger on iPad and smaller on iPhones. Also it should look fine in both orientations.

[image]

I want the UIImageView size to be kept proportionate to screen size. These are the constraints applied till now :

[image]

Here topConstraint is an outlet which has the following code :

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        topConstraint.constant = 40
    }
    else {
        topConstraint.constant = 12
    }
}
```

If i give only leading trailing top and bottom constraints then it shows red lines depicting missing constraints as follows :

[image]

Please help. I am using swift 3 and xcode 8. I know its something to do with aspect ratio but mine is still not coming perfect.

Comment: Did you give a bottom constraint for date label ?

Comment: @SnehaGeorge Date label's bottom is set as ImageView.top = dateLabel.bottom + 16

Comment: Since you are using scroll view and here your image height is missing, thats why its shows red lines..

Answer (score 0):

Set aspect ratio `1:1` and see. It will stretch your `imageview` with proportion of `1:1` according to minimum scale of device size (either height or width).

Note: Device orientation also plays important role here.

Comment: Also let me know exact detail of your query. How you want it to be displyed in iPad. Becasue 1:1 will also show image with respect to minimum dimension of screen size and for iPad, height and width has small difference in apsect ratio.
Let me know in detail, or share your source code.

Comment: I want the image to be seen in the shown size in portrait mode and in landscape I want it to look more or less like in portrait only(but little bigger)

Comment: I tried 1:1 but the image became bigger than current shown size in portrait

Comment: What's current size and do you want same size for all devices?

Comment: Current size is 311*216. I want the size to increase as device screen size increases

Comment: Share me your source code, if you can. I'll update & revert you according to your requirement.

Comment: My app is complete so can't share source code. Can you please create a short demo?

Comment: Ok, do one thing, share me design of this page only(that you have attached with this question), in a separate project, I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Your top label doesn't have enough constraints to know where it should be along the Y axis.
Let's have a look at your constraint along the Y axis starting from the bottom of your view. You set:

- the bottom of your view to be at 16p from the bottom of your detailLabel,
- your detailLabel top at 16p from the imageView bottom,
- then you have the aspect ratio of your image which given the width (you set it through the leading constraint of the imageView and the X-center) is setting the height
- imageView top at 16p from detailLabel bottom
- dateLabel top at 4p from titleLabel bottom
- you didn't set the constraint starting from the top of the titleLabel and going to the top of the view.

So in conclusion, you are missing one constraint. Set the top constraint of you title label and you should be fine. Also, I would delete the X center constraint of your imageView and replace it by a trailing constraint of 32pt (same as the leading one, it's easier to read, will display the same and there's less inferring to do)

Comment: There is a top already for the titleLabel. I tried the trailing constraint part also before posting this question

Comment: can you update your screenshots then, because the top constraint of the title label is not visible in your screenshot of the left panel

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding suggestion is:

constraints to imageview : Leading ,Trailing , Top and Height.

Now give outlet to height constraint.

Then for bottom label,Constraints are: Top,Bottom,Leading,Trailing.

Now set your imageView's height constraint's constant according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

To make image size according to screen size, you need to set aspect ration constraint with respect to your current view(current screen size).

From the give constraints, you are missing height and width of image view as its not possible to infer its dimension until image is set to it, so you need to give height & width to the image view, the red line will be removed automatically.

**Why red line are there?**

> Since you are using scroll view, the scrollview's content size is depended on the its subview and the constraints given to its subview.

So please make sure that all the constraints to the subview are given correctly. Otherwise scrollview will not be scrolled.